# In IntelliJ, how do I run a maven build, execute the resulting application and connect a debugger in one step?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

My current development flow is:

1. Code (in IntelliJ)
2. Run Maven build to package the application (in IntelliJ)
3. Start the application locally (using a script, mvn exec is not suitable)
4. Connect the debugger (in IntelliJ using Run -> Attach to Process)
5. Repeat from 1

Is there a way to package steps 2-4 into a one-click process in IntelliJ?  Currently I have to start the Maven build, wait for it to complete, then start the application (outside of IntelliJ at the moment), then come back into IntelliJ to connect the debugger.

Since computers are better at waiting and not getting distracted than I am, I would like this to be 1 step instead of 3.

Comment: I usually don't do that.  Why would I want to?

Comment: Hi @duffymo I've added my motivation to describe why I want to do this.

Comment: Make `mvn exec` work, then debug that Maven instantiation

Answer (score 2):

In itelliJ IDEA you can create configuration (use remote debug for your purpose):
[image: Configurations menu]
[image: Create debug configuration]

Then you should click on "plus" symbol in "before launch" section:
[image]
So you can create sequence of actions which will be executed before remote will be run. You can add your maven goal to build project, external tool for running application (or use "Run another configuration which will run application). Then remote debug will connect to your app.